# Get "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials" when I'm copying file from S3 to EC2 using aws cli

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

When login EC2 as ec2-user and run the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/test/test.txt /home/ec2-user/
```

I got the following error:

```
fatal error: Unable to locate credentials
```

My bucket and my EC2 are created by the same account and in the same region. Why my EC2 can't access my S3 object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that it is caused by missing role. In order to access S3 objects from EC2, I need to assign a role during the EC2 creation, and the role should has the access rights to S3.

Answer (score 1):

Sync should work.

```
aws s3 sync s3://s3-bucket-name/folder /home/ec2-user
```

Don't forget to set write access to the S3 bucket and set the IAM roles

Answer (score -1):

You can set up the configuration of the AWS S3 bucket using the command:

```
aws configure
```

Then try; it should work.