# Why am I having AWS credential errors in my AWS terminal setup?

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, credentials

Wanted to learn AWS and found the tutorial [Build a Serverless Web Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-serverless-web-app-lambda-apigateway-s3-dynamodb-cognito/module-1/). In my research the closest Q&A I could find for my issue was [Unable to locate credentials aws cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485653/unable-to-locate-credentials-aws-cli).

My process has been:

- Created a repo in Github
- Navigated to IAM and created a user `trainer`. Tutorial didn't specify policies so chose `AdministratorAccess`. Per instructions went the <kbd>Security credentials</kbd> and <kbd>Create access key</kbd>. Downloaded the file locally.
- Went to [Configuration basics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-creds-import) and did [Importing a key pair via .CSV file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-creds-import) with the command of:

```
aws configure import --csv file:///Users/path/to/file/aws-training.csv
```

params:

```
User name: trainer
Access key ID: ****57
Secret access key: *****1b
```

but then found that the file didn't contain `region` or `format` so did:

```
aws configure --profile trainer
```

and re-did all values based on the CSV ([Quick Setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-quickstart.html)):

```
AWS Access Key ID: ****57
AWS Secret Access Key: *****1b
Default region name: us-east-1
Default output format: json
```

Made sure to reboot my terminal and locally in a directory I run the command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://wildrydes-us-east-1/WebApplication/1_StaticWebHosting/website ./ --recursive
```

The terminal has a delay then throws:

```
fatal error: Unable to locate credentials
```

### Research

Q&As I've read through to try and see if I could diagnose the problem:

- [aws cli with shell script: upload failed: Unable to locate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63771820/aws-cli-with-shell-script-upload-failed-unable-to-locate-credentials)
- [Bash with AWS CLI - unable to locate credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425838/bash-with-aws-cli-unable-to-locate-credentials)
- [Unable to locate credentials aws cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68485653/unable-to-locate-credentials-aws-cli)
- [Unable to locate credentials in boto3 AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71732270/unable-to-locate-credentials-in-boto3-aws)
- [Get "fatal error: Unable to locate credentials" when I'm copying file from S3 to EC2 using aws cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55333439/get-fatal-error-unable-to-locate-credentials-when-im-copying-file-from-s3-to)
- [Unable to locate credentials when trying to copy files from s3-bucket to my ec2-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56575705/unable-to-locate-credentials-when-trying-to-copy-files-from-s3-bucket-to-my-ec2)

How can I resolve my error of `Unable to locate credentials` and what am I doing wrong or misunderstanding?

---

Per the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74209477/why-am-i-having-aws-credential-errors-in-my-aws-terminal-setup#comment131022013_74209477):

> Check the content of `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`

#### credentials

command:

```
nano ~/.aws/credentials
```

renders:

```
[training]
aws_access_key_id = *****57
aws_secret_access_key = ***1b
[trainer]
aws_access_key_id = *****57
aws_secret_access_key = ***1b
```

#### config

command:

```
nano ~/.aws/config
```

renders:

```
[profile training]
region = us-east-1
output = json
[profile trainer]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

Comment: Hello @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ! Just a first checkup: if you do in your command line `aws configure` the last 4 characters from the Access Key ID do they match with the one that you import?

Comment: From what I'm seeing in the docs I would say yes.

Comment: Check the content of `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano edited in that info from those two files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've configured the profile with the name `trainer`. You didn't create a default profile, you created a named profile. You're getting the current error because the CLI tool is looking for a default profile, and you don't have one configured.

In order to use the `trainer` profile you either have to add `--profile trainer` to every `aws` command you run in the command line, or you need to set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable inside your command line environment:

```
export AWS_PROFILE=trainer
```

---

It looks like you also tagged this with `nodejs`, so I recommend going the environment variable route, which will also work with the nodeJS AWS SDK.